# In travis CI, is it possible to skip an installation step for Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, travis-ci

A travis build, which uses

```
install:
    pip install unittest2
```

fails on Python 3 since unittest2 does not support Python 3. Is there a way to ignore that row for Python 3 builds, or just generally to ignore errors with that installation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Travis provides links to a few [example](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/python/#Examples) projects that use different versions of python.

I'm a fan of the [tornado](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/.travis.yml) one, as it shows how you can manage each version very explicitly.

```
install:
    - if [[ $TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION == 2* ]]; then pip install unittest2; fi
```

Using this line, `unittest2` will only install on the 2.x branch of Python. You can add further `if/fi` statements to tune your installs for the Python 3.x branch.